# How do I set a column to return a value in a select statement

Tags: sql, select

So if i do a statement such as

```
Select column1, column2
from dbo.table
```

How would i return column1 as the actual data and column2 as a fixed value, if i wanted to have column 2 to always show the same value.Im building an output file and need to put in some predefined results.

```
Column1         Column2
-------         -------
dog             A
cat             A
bird            A
```

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would then select a constant value:

```
Select column1, 'A' as column2
from dbo.table
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this.

Answer (score 0):

select a *constant* value :

```
SELECT t.Column1, 'A' AS Column2
FROM dbo.table t
```